# jQuery code that manipulates DOM on window.load doesn't always run

Tags: jquery, window-load

I need to center text in a select list. There is no cross browser and device method using CSS only, so ive used JavaScript to set a text indent.

The code takes the text from the select list, adds it to a span (which with css makes the text the same size), and measures the width of the span. With that value it takes some simple maths to work out what the text indent needs to be.

```
$(window).load(function() {
  function textIndentFunc () {
     textString = $('#from-1 :selected').text();
     $('#hidden').text(textString);
     textWidth = $('#hidden').width();
     inputWidth = $('#from-1 select').width();
     indentMy = (inputWidth / 2) - (textWidth / 2);
     $('#from-1').css('text-indent',indentMy); 
}
$('#from-1 select').change(function() {
    textIndentFunc();
});
textIndentFunc();
});
```

Most of the time this code works fine but sometimes doesn't appear to do anything, in which case refreshing the page normally fixes it. Why is this code being so temperamental? Is it to do with having to manipulation the dom?

Thanks

Comment: Does the .change() event fire once you change the item ?

Comment: Yes, that always seems to work fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do `$(document).ready()` **not** `$(window).load()`

When invoking `$(document).ready()` your function is called once the DOM is processed and ready to be manipulated while `load()` will callback once all the assets are loaded(images, sounds).

Comment: Im having the same issue. In face the code is more unreliable now. FYI my code already had both window load and dom ready doing different things.